# Global and local Ids usage in an Algorithm in OpenCL

Tags: 2d, opencl

well I posted some weeks ago about an error I had into my openCL implementation but it seems I have to start from the beggining. So, how should be implemented the next algorithm in OpenCL.

```
int m = 10;
int n = 10;
//arrA[] has m elements
//arrB[] has n elements
//arrC[] has m x n elements

for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
    arrC[i x j] = arrA[i] x arrB[j];
  }
}
```

For this case I need just knowing how to handle this with the global and local ids.... because there is where I am a little lost. Thank you so much

Comment: Can you edit the question and share your first attempt and we can try to correct it instead of giving the answer?

Comment: If you use a 2d-kernel, then only 3 lines are enough. 1 to get gobal id of "i" dimension and 1 to get global id of "j" dimension and a computing line such as   "arrC[i * n + j] = arrA[i] * arrB[j];". Also a kernel has a function definition with arguments probably __global float *arrA and __global float *arrB

Comment: Hiii, thank you two for your interest, the code I already have will be posted down here!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I currently have (This is an extraction of the real code that will perform a reduction because I need to get a maximum value).

```
"sampleKernel(__global const double *bufferX,"
"             __global const double *bufferY,"
"             __global double* result,"
"             __const int lengthX,"
"             __const int lengthY){"
"    const int index_a = get_global_id(0);"//Get the global indexes for 2D reference
"    const int index_b = get_global_id(1);"
"    const int local_index = get_local_id(0);"//Current thread id -> Should be the same as index_a * lengthY + index_b;
"    if (local_index < (lengthX * lengthY)) {"// Load data into local memory
"       if(index_a < lengthX && index_b < lengthY)"
"       {"
"           result[local_index] = bufferX[index_a] * bufferY[index_b];"
"       }"
"    } "
"}";
```

Maybe I should use a get_local_id(1) too, and use the thread Id as local_id_1 * N + local_id_2 where N is the maximum local_id_2 value.